# How I got error 'Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'app-customer-list' is not a known element'

Tags: javascript, angular

i am trying to load a component but i get this error.

```
eRROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-customer-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-customer-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-customer-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
</p>
```

All code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkciqv?file=src/app/orders/order-list/order-list.component.html

Check component:
Order -> Order-list -> Order.component.html

why not loaded ? Why is error? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in your customers module, you need to `export` component(s) that you want to expose to other modules using the `exports` property:

**customers.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CustomersRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [CustomerListComponent],
  exports: [CustomerListComponent]
})
export class CustomersModule { }
```

Next you need to `import` the `CustomersModule` into the module that will be using the component(s) that were exported by that module:

**orders.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OrdersRoutingModule,
    CustomersModule
  ],
  declarations: [OrderListComponent]
})
export class OrdersModule { }
```

Comment: Ok work but what example if CustomerList no route then only like a shared component